# How to redirect to another page with restify?

Tags: node.js, restify

Restify redirect does'nt work

I have login page, when user enters email and password. If data is correct, he should redirect to another page. But it's not working.

```
const restify = require('restify')

var server = restify.createServer()
server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url)
});

server.post('/login/:email/:password', function (request, response, next) {
    const email = request.params.email
    const password = request.params.password

    if (authentication.credentialsIsCorrect(email, password)) {
        response.redirect('https://www.google.com', next)
        // response.redirect('/index.html', next)
        // response.redirect('localhost:8080/index.html', next)
        return
    }

})
```

There is no errors of exceptions. It's just dont redirect

Comment: `const restify = requre('restify')` should be `const restify = require('restify')`. Notice the **requre** to **require** change. Also, based on your code shown to us, `port` and `instance` are *undefined*.

Comment: i just made a typo here. My code has no syntax errors. But redirect not working

Comment: Are you positive that the authentication is correct? Also, I'm assuming that credentialsIsCorrect is NOT asynchronous. Is that true?

Comment: It's true, but it's not important. It's just compares password with hardcoded string. And it's not matter of authentication, it's matter of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from frontend after you get a sucess status of 200.